# Issues with File System and Settings file in Drupal clone from Github using MAMP

Tags: php, git, drupal, drupal-7, mamp-pro

I am brand new to Drupal and was looking around to find issues related to mine, but I have cloned a repo of a Drupal build so that i can collaborate with my team and also install it locally using MAMP.

I was able to clone it successfully into my htdocs folder, but when i went through the Drupal installation process I got the following errors see below in grey since i can't post an image because I don't have a 10 reputation yet.

> File system    The directory sites/default/files is not writable. An
>   automated attempt to create this directory failed, possibly due to a
>   permissions problem. To proceed with the installation, either create
>   the directory and modify its permissions manually or ensure that the
>   installer has the permissions to create it automatically. For more
>   information, see INSTALL.txt or the online handbook.

and

> Settings file The settings file is not writable. The Drupal installer
>   requires write permissions to ./sites/default/settings.php during the
>   installation process. If you are unsure how to grant file permissions,
>   consult the online handbook.

Naturally I don't know what this means and was wondering what kind of problems I could expect if just ignore it, or better yet how to just resolve it and not go the route of unexpected errors later.

Any help on what this means or how it affects the install I would really appreciate.

Finally Drupal didn't ask whether an SQL database was installed and I'm not sure if that would've installed with the clone (I suspect not) but don't really know any advice on whether i should just get the SQL file from the Admin or if it is installed would be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A clean Drupal installation process includes creation of required tables (you provide the db username, password, host & db-name). Drupal also needs write permission on sites/default/files directory (It stores user uploaded stuff & cache related files).

You can know more about securing file permissions here: https://drupal.org/node/244924

For a local install what I do is, give 777 permission to sites/default directory. Later I change the permission of the settings.php file to 555 to get get rid of drupal warning messages.

For *nix machines, you can do `chmod -R 777 sites/default`
NOTE: this is just a quickfix and okay for local setup. Please set file permissions wisely in production/server setup.

Comment: Thanks Amar but I couldn't check out that link it didn't work for me. But where in the settings file would you include the 777 permission and how would it look like?

Comment: Also nearly the entire settings.php file is commented out, is this on purpose? And if so do i need to uncomment this section # $conf['proxy_server'] = '';
# $conf['proxy_port'] = 8080;
# $conf['proxy_username'] = '';
# $conf['proxy_password'] = '';
# $conf['proxy_user_agent'] = '';
# $conf['proxy_exceptions'] = array('127.0.0.1', 'localhost');

Comment: would i then put the 777 in the # $conf['proxy_server'] = '';